# Android - FileNotFoundException open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, samsung-galaxy

I have an application that in the login I download images from my server. 
in the first login, everything is work fine but when I uninstall the application and install it again I get this exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.gilapp.android.app/files/images/book_118.png:
>   open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

and can't save the image.

this happen while I'm trying to create output stream:

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
```

The images download fine just when I do the second installation after I go to **App info -> Storage -> clear data**

Another important point is that it happens only in Samsung's tablet: `SM-T800 (API level 23)`

In other devices it's not happening, the devices that I test: `Samsung SM-G900H (API level 23)`, `Asus P028 (API level 24)`,  `Samsung SM-G950F (API level 28)`

Comment: did you grant storage permission on this devices? can you share your code ?

Comment: Yes, this is all the permissions: 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: also need to get dangerous permission on run-time on Api-Level higher than 23. check the answer for how to get that.

Answer (score 12):

If your app is pointing to the android version 10.

In the manifest include under the application add

---

> `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

---

Note that this workaround no longer works in Android 11.

Comment: this is absolutely correct answer and solved my problem on Android 10. 
Thanks @viveksuggu !

Comment: I am still getting this error on android 11 with samsung devices.

Comment: How about Android 11? Any suggestions?

Comment: @SagarMaiyad , I am also facing same issue. Have you got solution ?

Comment: @GNK Nope, still getting this error on many devices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get [Run-time permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for write in storage. before saving your files check the permission.also there are some library for this work: [Android-Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/235?sort=rating)

is better to use a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) for accessing files in storage.

Comment: thanks, you're right, when I use run-time permission I don't get this exception. but you know why it happens only in Samsung's tablet: SM-T800 (API level 23)

Comment: your welcome, the runetime permission is added from api level 23 :)

Answer (score 1):

When you uninstall your application all files in `getExternalFilesDir()`are removed hence the `/images` directory has gone

After reinstall you can again write files to that directory for which you do not need any permission.

Not at runtime. Not in manifest.

But you want them in the ..../images directory.

You have to care for that directory yourself.

Check if the directory exists and then create it before you try to put a file in it.

Answer (score 1):

First, check whether you have implemented scoped storage logic in the app. You can also use android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" But this legacyStoragePermission is limited to version 10. You need to implement scoped logic.

Also, check whether your targetSDKVersion value is 30 or greater or not, this is needed if you are using the app in Device android version 30 or more.