# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) while accessing the video

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

My code works in all android versions except android 11 . In android 11 i am stuck with the following exception **open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**. What is the solution for the error .

```
val widthHeight = TrimmerUtils.getVideoWidthHeight(this, uri)
 var width = widthHeight[0]
 var height = widthHeight[1]
 var bitrate = ""
 if (widthHeight[0] > 900 || widthHeight[1] > 900){
     width
     height
     bitrate = "1M"
 } else
     bitrate= "400k"
```

What i tried is

Added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

added

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Added

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
        101)
}
```

Reference :

[When I update from Android 10 to 11, I get "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202842/when-i-update-from-android-10-to-11-i-get-open-failed-eacces-permission-deni)

[Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)

[How to resolve fileNotFoundException - open failed: EACCES (permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70941142/how-to-resolve-filenotfoundexception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied)

[Error reading and writing files on android 11 open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921791/error-reading-and-writing-files-on-android-11-open-failed-eacces-permission-de)

[Android - FileNotFoundException open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809266/android-filenotfoundexception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied)

[open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) ANDROID 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69923726/open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-android-11)